# Is there any way to load the Three.js library along with GLTFLoader and OrbitControls without using npm or importing modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js, gltf

I am currently trying to integrate the Three.js library into a development environment that does not allow the use of npm or modules.
I have tried to install the libraries at different versions (120, 132, 135) etc. and adding a script tag:  &  and this has actually worked when i was testing in vscode Live Server.
However when i added these libraries to the development environment, i keep getting this error when trying to load the GLTFLoader: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor.

This is my code:

```
 const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

This is the start of the GLTFLoader library which i think is relevant to my issue:

```
THREE.GLTFLoader = ( function () {

class GLTFLoader {
    constructor(manager) {

        this.manager = (manager !== undefined) ? manager : THREE.DefaultLoadingManager;
        this.dracoLoader = null;

    }
}
```

}
The library seems to returning a function, however even when is alter the code to call a function, i get this error: THREE.GTLFLoader is not a function:

```
   const loader = THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

Ive been stuck on this for a while, so any help or hint in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640216/using-the-three-js-library-without-modules Have you tried to apply the comment in the other question?